# How to sync python files from PyCharm IDE to GitHub Automatically?

Tags: python, github, pycharm, stack-overflow

I'm currently using PyCharm IDE to learn Python. I am not aware of how to sync my file automatically to GitHub. Or to be precise I want my code to automatically sync as I type, to my GitHub repo. Like I want the file to exist in GitHub and edit it over my IDE.

Is there any solution for this to happen?

Regards,
Kausik

Answer (score 0):

That is not how git (or Github) works. Version control systems are designed to capture milestones in your project. I think you're confusing git with file management cloud services (e.g., Dropbox or Google Drive). If you need something that would sync your files with each "save" you make to a file then services like Dropbox are what you looking for.

However, version control systems (e.g., git) are much better suited for code management if you adjust your workflow to follow how they were intended to be used. In PyCharm, after each milestone (e.g., a bug fix or a new feature implementation) you would do the following:

- Stage changed files by checking them.
- Commit the changes by adding a commit message.
- Push changes to the remote repository.

All these can be found within the Commit window in PyCharm (View >> Tool Windows >> Commit). All the three steps above can be done in one click

One last thing. If your goal is to collaborate with someone else in real-time, then PyCharm has a new feature called "Code with me" (Tools >> Code With Me ...). I don't know if it is available for free but the idea is that you would invite friends and change the code base together in real-time. And eventually, you would push the changes to the remote repository.